# Inconsistency using docker to connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, vagrant

## Versions

- OS: macOS High Sierra: 10.13.6
- Docker: 18.06.0-ce-mac70 (26399)
- Compose: 1.22.0

I have an existing Wordpress site that I want to containrise. The database of which, for the sake of testing, is running on a local Vagrant VM, eventually the database will be one hosted on AWS. Eventually after testing is complete I'll create a `Dockerfile` but for now whilst testing, I'm using `docker-compose`.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   wordpress:
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
        - ./wordpress/:/var/www/html
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST_IP}
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
```

As you can see there are some environment variables used from my `.env`. Running `docker-compose config` shows that the information has been correctly loaded so that's not the problem.

## Output

```
docker-compose up

[website name]_wordpress_1 is up-to-date
Attaching to [website name]_wordpress_1
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection timed out
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection timed out
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection timed out
```

Finally, the weird thing is that was working once before with this exact configuration and even fixed the same issue in the past. I fixed it by restarting the vagrant VM and restarting the docker daemon. Doing the same now though hasn't solved the problem.

What could be the root of this problem?

## EDIT

I changed the `WORDPRESS_*` to `MYSQL_*` in the `docker-compose` file. The output from the terminal suggests that it's working. However, when going to localhost and the appropriate it takes forever to load and when it finally reaches I get the page outputting "Error establishing a database connection".

Again not sure what's going wrong. I can log into the database with the same credentials using my SQL client (sequel pro) just fine and everything works as expected. Which leads me to assume that something is incorrect in the `docker-compose` file itself.

## EDIT 2

Getting into the running image with `docker exec -t [image name] bash` and then pinging the database IP showed it wasn't returning anything but in my own terminal it returns packets fine. So this is an internal network issue it seems?

Changing the details of the database to the live SQL server means it all works as expected so for now, I'll have to stick with that and just be careful. I would still like to find out what the issue is though with the internal network of my docker image not being able to connecting to the local database.

Answer (score 3):

Docker containers cannot by default access the host when running in a bridged networking mode. When your container attempts to connect to localhost, it is connecting to its own container - not the host MySQL instance.

Your best bet would be to run a MySQL container alongside which is fairly simple to do with docker-compose.

A new docker compose file should look something fairly like this:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress/:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASS}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
volumes:
  db_data:
```

The reason I use `mysql` as the hostname in the main container config is that docker-compose sets up these hostnames for you depending on how you name the service.

Alternatively, since you're running Docker for Mac - you may be able to access the host MySQL by using `docker.for.mac.localhost` as the hostname.

Comment: I'm still fairly new to docker so if anyone spots any errors or unnecessary details in the compose file suggestion, feel free to edit.

Comment: My assumption was that because it's running in the VM it treats it as a different machine. The IP address for example is something like 192.x.x.x. as opposed to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @shmink ah that's quite possible, although I imagine the virtual machine itself may have it's own bridge and complications... Since Docker is running in a VM itself, you may have to jump through a lot of networking hoops to get that setup working.